# Intellij Error Duplicate Mapper Class with Auto Compile

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, jhipster

Intellij Ultimate 2020.2 Java & Jhipster project which uses Map Struct and Mapper classes. The build tool is gradle. Intellij configuered as per [here](https://www.jhipster.tech/configuring-ide-idea/) (bottom of page), however I could not find the option to configure all build tasks to gradle.

Project was fine until I enabled **Settings > Compiler > Build Project Automatically** setting:

[image]

Then I get duplicate class errors when running the gradle build task. This is the duplicate class the IDE complains about. For example:

C:\Users\User\IdeaProjects\Dep\build\generated\sources\annotationProcessor\java\main\test\pot\service\mapper\TaskCodeMapperImpl.java:16: error: duplicate class: test.pot.service.mapper.TaskCodeMapperImpl
public class TaskCodeMapperImpl implements TaskCodeMapper {

[image]

Invalidate caches and restart does not fix the issue.

**UPDATED**

[image]

Comment: Could you please attach screenshot from "Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle"?

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug when IDE will uses it's own builder for auto-make (even though **Build and Run Using: Gradle** is set) when **Build Project Automatically** option is enabled: [IDEA-212052](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-212052).

As a workaround please disable **Build Project Automatically** option.

Comment: Disable which option?

Comment: I've clarified the answer.

Answer (score 0):

But still if You wanna let **Build Project Automatically** option,

there is another solution `-Djps.track.ap.dependencies=false` in **User-loca build process VM options (overrides Shared options):**

[image]

It was solved [IDEA-250718](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-250718)